How to reverse audio normalization using python?
The application I used to export my edited audio was normalizing the audio which I don't want. I have the original audio that doesn't have normalization, and the new audio that has some parts shifted around to match video timing but is normalized by the application.
Is it possible to reverse the normalization using the original audio file? Technically it should be trivial to detect the peaks of each file to calculate the scaling factor, right?
This code should do that:
def adjust_volume(original_path, normalized_path, output_path):
    # Load the original and normalized audio
    original_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(original_path)
    normalized_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(normalized_path)

    # Calculate the difference in dBFS
    db_difference = original_audio.dBFS - normalized_audio.dBFS

    # Adjust normalized audio
    adjusted_audio = normalized_audio + db_difference

    # Export the adjusted audio
    adjusted_audio.export(output_path, format='wav')


As you can see the top parts are aligned but the bottom parts do not. Is it because I need to scale above the center line using a different factor vs below the center line?


"Is it possible to reverse the normalization using the original audio file?" I don't understand. First off, the point of normalization is that many inputs can map to the same output and information is lost. Second, if it were possible, wouldn't you just get the original audio file back? So if you already have that, why is there anything to do?

Are you sure that isn't just a visualization problem? If not, there is an artificial offset

@KarlKnechtel why information is lost?  Normalization should take the highest original peak, raising it to zero dBFS and moving all other relative values proportionally

@KarlKnechtel. no I wouldn't get the original audio back because as mentioned in the OP, I slightly edited the audio for syncing to video, i.e. offset individual parts. I am not sure why information is lost though.

@pierpy I am not sure but I was displaying both audio in audacity. I thought maybe just using the same factor to scale it back doesn't work because I am not sure exactly how audio normalization is implemented but from what I see both sides are scaled to get the peak reach the 0 db? I don't know if they are doing some centering to the audio itself. I know audacity has option for this but the app I was using it doesnt have any options.

@JoanVenge can you share a sample of your audio? I'm an sound engineer... I can try some analysis with pro softwares, like Pro Tools and similar

@pierpy Oh, sorry. I was thinking of compression (in the audio sense, not the general file sense).

@JoanVenge I can confirm the problem. Audacity does not introduce any visualization artifact, it's real. If I normalize your original audio in Pro Tools, the problem disappears

@pierpy thx a lot so you mean normalize the original audio or the already normalized one? so is there a way to reverse the normalization done to get back to the original one?

I mean, the problem in your normalized file is real; there is no way to go back, without implementing yourself an undo routine, keeping track of all modifications. Anyway. please note: this is not a relevant problem. The real problem is the noise in your rec, It comes out in a very obvious way in the normalized audio
